# Setting up Facebook SDK for post processing leads to error messages in console

Tags: xcode, facebook, appdelegate

I have no clear effects from this, but am in the final phases of a project and am trying to heed any warnings. I receive 3 warning logs from FB each time I launch in the Xcode console when adding the following line to App Delegate under `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)`:

```
FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

"...FBSDKLog: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection cannot be started before Facebook SDK initialized."

If I remove this line of course then if I attempt to log in with Facebook post processing does not complete and the login does not occur. So, sanity check: am I to ignore these warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook requires a line for post-processing in AppDidLaunch, which the first time the app launches will run prior to the SDK being initialized: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph/. The line is therefore moot when you first launch, but FB is happy to clog your console anyway. If you remove this line FB will be unable to process a login appropriately in an app, so we will have to live with this meaningless "warning."

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this warning. In my case it showed up constantly and not only on startup. The reason was that I had configured this in my `Info.plist`.

```
<key>FacebookAutoInitEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

I fixed this by executing this after the user has accepted the terms and conditions:

```
ApplicationDelegate.initializeSDK(nil)
```

Disclaimer: This doesn't answer the question directly, but I wanted to post it here since many people may end up here googling for this error message. I now have the same issue as stated in the question above and I don't know how to get rid of the warning on startup.

**UPDATE for iOS SDK version >= 9.0.0**

With version 9.0.0 the `FacebookAutoInitEnabled` flag was removed, and one needs to initialize the SDK explicitly with the `initializeSDK` method or implicitly by calling it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

➡️ [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md?fbclid=IwAR26GzSRcYyoiNYdGAOOaXcuMqCvLMZUEXbl20PbswPzpIy2pscjRD6DHks)

Comment: This is helpful, but perhaps better as a comment.

Comment: @MikePandolfini I had it as a comment first, but to make the content more structured and less confusing I made it an answer.

Comment: Any documentation on this ?

Comment: @neobie I've updated the post and linked the docs :)